# Can I use something else than curly bracket in nftables.conf?

Tags: ansible, nftables

I am trying to template stateful nftables configuration file with Ansible.

- Ansible uses Jinja for templating and Jinja uses curly braces for variables:

`{{ variable }}`

- Nftables configuration uses curly braces for grouping variables together:

`{ 192.168.3.0/24, 192.168.1.0/24 }`.

- Escaping Jinja2 curly braces looks like this:

`{%raw%} { {%endraw%}` or like this:

`{{ '{' }}`

This look extremely UGLY and hard to read.
Any way to make NFtables use a different character than curly braces? Like `[` or `(` or `<`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using ansible's [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html) module, then you can configure the variable interpolation markers used by Jinja:

> Also, you can override jinja2 settings by adding a special header to template file. i.e. #jinja2:variable_start_string:'[%', variable_end_string:'%]', trim_blocks: False which changes the variable interpolation markers to [% var %] instead of {{ var }}. This is the best way to prevent evaluation of things that look like, but should not be Jinja2.

The [jinja documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#high-level-api) has a list of the various markers that can be changed.